# Combine list of vectors to a data.frame, with list number

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe

We have a list of vectors (of different lengths):

```
foo <- list(1:3,NULL,2:7)
```

What we need is a data.frame with two columns: item and list number, like below:

```
data.frame(Item=c(1:3,2:7), List=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3))
```

Here the `Item` column is the vector of items in `foo`, and `List` columns shows to which list of `foo` each item belongs.

This can be done like below:

```
data.frame(Item=unlist(foo), 
           List=unlist(lapply(seq_along(foo), function(i) rep(i, length(foo[[i]])))))
```

But I am looking for more creative and efficient solutions. Do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer sort of depends on the type of data in "foo", but you can try `stack` after adding `names` to your `list`:

```
names(foo) <- seq_along(foo)
stack(foo)
#   values ind
# 1      1   1
# 2      2   1
# 3      3   1
# 4      2   3
# 5      3   3
# 6      4   3
# 7      5   3
# 8      6   3
# 9      7   3
# Warning message:
#   In stack.default(foo) : non-vector elements will be ignored
```

---

A slightly more compact version of your current approach would be to use `sapply` instead of `lapply`:

```
> foo <- list(1:3,NULL,2:7)
> data.frame(Item = unlist(foo), List = rep(seq_along(foo), sapply(foo, length)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr` you can have more readble solution:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(seq_along(foo),
       function(x)data.frame(Item=foo[[x]],
                             List=rep(x,length(foo[[x]]))))

 Item List
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    2    3
5    3    3
6    4    3
7    5    3
8    6    3
9    7    3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
data.frame(Item = unlist(foo),
           List = rep(seq_along(foo), sapply(foo, length)))
```

Replacing `sapply(foo, length)` with `vapply(foo, length, integer(1))` or `unlist(lapply(foo, length))` will also be a little more efficient. And I don't think you can go faster.

Less efficient but somewhat creative is:

```
i <- sapply(foo, Negate(is.null))
do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, Item = foo[i], List = seq_along(foo)[i]))
```

Comment: +1 for the alternatives. I guess we posted our `sapply` alternatives at about the same time.